# Retrieve words which start with $$, $ from a String

Tags: java

How to retrieve special strings from a query as below:

```
SELECT * from Employees  where yearNumber_MO = $$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth \n\t    and TESTING_STATUS = $$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Group \n\t    and WorkflowName = '$PMWorkName' \n\t    and CUSTOMFIELD = '$$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Region' \n\t    and Type = '$$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Type' \n\t  )
```

Want the above to return stringarray with

```
TestCheck_EmployeeMonth, TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Group, PMWorkName, TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Region, TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Type
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the regexp `(?<=[$]{1,2})[a-zA-Z_]+`

```java
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=[$]{1,2})[a-zA-Z_]+").matcher("SELECT * from Employees  where yearNumber_MO = $$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth \\n\\t    and TESTING_STATUS = $$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Group \\n\\t    and WorkflowName = '$PMWorkName' \\n\\t    and CUSTOMFIELD = '$$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Region' \\n\\t    and Type = '$$TestCheck_EmployeeMonth_Type' \\n\\t  )");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
return result;
```